# How ADO CursorLocation Property works?

Tags: vbscript, ado

I just have been introduced to the ***ADO CursorLocation Property*** of the *ADO*. Now I got to what `CursorLocation Property` by its definition only.

The CursorLocation property sets or returns a long value that indicates the location of the cursor service.Default value is `AdUseServer`.

Basically I am looking for any in-depth knowledge of this property. If any one have please share. What are the circumstances I have to think about it and How it works in the Real world programming?

Again how the below two works and what their purposes are to set?

- objConnection.CursorLocation
- objRecordset.CursorLocation

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Start your research with the [Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa141422%28v=office.10%29.aspx):

> The server cursor engine is provided by the OLE DB provider and the
>   database engine itself
>
> The client cursor engine is an OLE DB service component that buffers
>   and copies the specified records to a temporary table that is stored
>   locally in memory, or on disk, if the number of records is
>   sufficiently large.

As searching the net for "cursorlocation adUseClient adUseServer" will result in isolated snippets of information (some of them dubious), use a book - e.g. [Roff ADO](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565924154.do) - to get the background/context needed to apply your knowledge about cursorlocations to your specific problems.

Comment: My bad I am not able to download that e-book. company firewall policy restricts me to get it download! :(

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU - that's what bookstores and libraries are for.

Comment: Any good books on `Excel VBA` would you suggest me? if you have no problem. Just asking you as I trust and respect your knowledge .